# Edit.NavigateToLollipop removed from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2022

According to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> should reveal the currently opened file in the solution explorer (the command in the "Keyboard" options is `Edit.NavigateToLollipop`).

In my installation, it doesn't appear that this command even exists.  It worked in previous versions.  Was it removed from 2022?

I do have R# installed, which remaps some key bindings, but I would expect that the command should still be there.

I've checked this on multiple computers and it seems to be the case on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using resharper, you can map Shift+Alt+L to "Resharper.ReSharper_LocateInSolutionOrAssemblyExplorer" in VS under options > Environment > Keyboard

[VS2022 options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMoPf.png)